# traslation view with geofield and openlayer

Tags: i18n-l10n, google-maps, javascript, location

i have a view format geofield map , i have build with openlayer  some positions and area on the map , in french the map is displayer with markers and area and i can have link from this markers  and area to content  , but when i choose arabic with arabic selector , the map and markers are not displayed 
i can't found solution for displaying map in arabic . The translation for other view is good 
can you help me please
i have drupal 7.41
openlayer 7.x-2.0-beta11
geoPHP 7.x-1.7+7-dev
Geofield Map 7.x-2.3
Views translation 7.x-3.x-dev